# Eudoxus' principle's inequality question

Tags: inequality

I have a question about inequality from Eudoxus' principle.

The principle may be phrased as follows.

Let $$M_0$$ and $$\varepsilon $$ be the two given magnitudes, and $$M_1,M_2, M_3,\cdot \cdot \cdot ,$$ a sequence such that $$M_1< \frac{1}{2}M_0, M_2<\frac{1}{2}M_1, M_3< \frac{1}{2}M_2,\cdot \cdot \cdot $$ Then we want to conclude that $$M_n<\varepsilon$$ for some n. To see that this is so, choose an integer N such that $$(N+1)\varepsilon>M_0$$
Then $$\varepsilon$$ is at most half of $$(N+1)\varepsilon$$, so it follows that $$N_\varepsilon\geq \frac{1}{2}M_0>M_1$$ Similarly, $$\varepsilon$$ is at most half of $$N_\varepsilon$$, so $$(N-1)\varepsilon\geq\frac{1}{2}M_1>M_2$$ Proceeding in this way, at each step subtracting $$\varepsilon$$ (which is at most half) from the left-hand-side and halving the right-hand-side, we arrive in N steps at the desired inequality $$\varepsilon>M_N$$

In this phrase I don't understand how $$>\rightarrow\geq$$ this transition happens. Instead, all I could get was $$N_\varepsilon>\frac{1}{2}M_0>M_1$$ letting $$\varepsilon\leq\frac{(N+1)\varepsilon }{2}$$

I need help to get this inequality $$N_\varepsilon\geq \frac{1}{2}M_0$$ From our settings.
Or is there something I'm missing?